# Hibernate Restrictions.isEmpty() is not working

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to learn hibernate. Right now I am studying criteria query. Here I have got trouble with Restrictions.isEmpty(). Can anyone please help me on this please ? Here are my attempts below ::

In my method >>>

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(EmployeeCriteria.class);
        cr.add(Restrictions.isEmpty("salary"));
        List results = cr.list();           
        for (Iterator iterator = results.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            EmployeeCriteria employee = (EmployeeCriteria) iterator.next();
            System.out.println("#####  - Employee #" + employee.getId() + " - #####");
            System.out.println("===============================");
            System.out.print("Employee ID: " + employee.getId());
            System.out.print(" ||  First Name: " + employee.getFirstName());
            System.out.print(" ||  Last Name: " + employee.getLastName());
            System.out.println(" ||  Salary: " + employee.getSalary());
        }
```

And it's giving this error >>>

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Property path [criteria.EmployeeCriteria.salary] does not reference a collection
at org.hibernate.criterion.AbstractEmptinessExpression.getQueryableCollection(AbstractEmptinessExpression.java:84)
at org.hibernate.criterion.AbstractEmptinessExpression.toSqlString(AbstractEmptinessExpression.java:63)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getWhereCondition(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:380)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:113)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:82)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.<init>(CriteriaLoader.java:92)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1697)
at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
```

**MY EmployeeCriteria POjo**

```
    import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_criteria")
public class EmployeeCriteria {
   @Id @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "id")
   private int id;

   @Column(name = "first_name")
   private String firstName;

   @Column(name = "last_name")
   private String lastName;

   @Column(name = "salary")
   private int salary;  

   public EmployeeCriteria() {}
   public int getId() {
      return id;
   }
   public void setId( int id ) {
      this.id = id;
   }
   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
   }
   public void setFirstName( String first_name ) {
      this.firstName = first_name;
   }
   public String getLastName() {
      return lastName;
   }
   public void setLastName( String last_name ) {
      this.lastName = last_name;
   }
   public int getSalary() {
      return salary;
   }
   public void setSalary( int salary ) {
      this.salary = salary;
   }
}
```

Comment: Show us your mapping. That part where you describe EmployeeCriteria.salary.

Comment: @talex, I have added the pojo which is annotated. thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`isEmpty()` is a method for lists. You are checking salary, which probably isn't a list, but more like a float or something. Use something like `criteria.add(Restrictions.ne("salary",""));` or `criteria.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("salary"));` instead.

Comment: thanks for your reply. isNull() or isNotNull() works fine. I am studying and fall in problem with isEmpty() and isNotEmpty(). Trying to make this work.

Comment: Then create a class that contains a list. You can try to query the list with `isEmpty()`.